# Laravel number_format() incorrect, bad number translation when reloaded and updated into database

Tags: php, laravel, numbers, format, display

I need your help to understand the mysterious way Laravel is playing with me and numbers !

I have a view on my blade.php where I have several :

> {!! Form::text('lim_dma',number_format( $newclient->lim_dma,2,'.',','),['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

The user will store for the first time a number , for example **10000**, and the page will reload the data from my database, displaying **10,000.00**

So far all good.

What I have discover is that if the user doesn't change anything and any data in the page ( in the Form::text), and submit a second time the data into my Controller, Laravel takes what's currently displayed in the textbox ( so **10,000.00**), but updates it in my databse as **10.00**...

Obviously Laravel understands ( badly) the coma in **10,000.00** displayed thanks to **number_format** in my blade.php.

I have tried to play with the type of ma variables in my database ( I tried double, I tried float => same bad result...).
I have tried too to fool the number_format by using a **space** instead of a **come** as thousand separator, but Laravel won't get fooled by this neither...

How do you do guys, in Laravel (mine is 5.1), to allow the user to store generic number ( such as 100000 or 50000), convert it, or display it with thousand separator without interferring after with the Controller's function and the update part of my model (see below) ?

> $newclient= Techdata::where('id_client','=',$id_client)->first();
>
> $newclient->update($request->all());
> Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a mutator to your `Techdata` model (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators):

```
public function setLimDmaAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['lim_dma'] = str_replace(',', '', $value);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jonas,

Of wow damn it works perfectly ! thanks a lot ! There are still part of Laravel I need to discover.
Models are very powrful in fact !
Have a good day !

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as accepted? This shows other users that the issue is resolved.

Comment: Hi Jonas, 
i have clicked on the upvote but it told me that I haven't yet 15 of reputation to do it.
I just clicked on the green arrow too, I haven't seen it before.
Thanks again for your help :)